# Error performing TLS handshake with Dovecot 2.3 upgrade

Tags: ssl, email-server, dovecot

I was getting the error message "Error performing TLS handshake: An unexpected TLS packet was received." in my email client after Dovecot was upgraded from dovecot-2.2 to dovecot-2.3. No email was being received by the Evolution email client. The server is: Debian 10/Buster/Sid. Server email configured using the guide from [https://workaround.org/ispmail/stretch][1].

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading to Debian 10 (Buster) last night I faced the same issue. I followed the second answer in this topic but didn't fix the issue. I then went to read the dovecot documentation https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration and what needed to add was a new entry for the dh.pem file on main dovecot.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

Then add manually the location of the dh.pem file, as with dovecot 2.3 doesn't do it automatically.

```
ssl_dh =</etc/dovecot/dh.pem
```

In my case, in the file /etc/dovecot/10-ssl.conf, the location of the dh.pem file was in /usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem so the step from OP did point me to the right direction.

For people changing the version of TSL to SSL1.2 be ware that the iOS native Mail app does only support SSL1 for POP3 and IMAP.

Comment: It looks like we had the same problem and it was solved in a similar way. Our configuration line for "ssl_dh =</etc/dovecot/dh.pem" is the same, however I have the configuration saved in a different configuration file than you. I also had extra steps of not having a dh.pem file and had to create one.

Answer (score 2):

I modified my original answer based on feedback from Steffen Ullrich.
I think Evolution and Dovecot interaction was my problem on upgrading dovecot. I got the email working by changing the ssl/tls configuration in dovecot. Make sure you have dovecot-2.3. All commands are done from the terminal. I first created a new Diffie Hellman parameters file.

```
cd /etc/dovecot
openssl dhparam 4096 > dh.pem
```

I removed the following lines in file “/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf”

```
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
```

I added and modified the following lines in file “/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf”

```
ssl_dh =</etc/dovecot/dh.pem
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW:!DH@STRENGTH
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
```

Restart the dovecot service

```
sudo systemctl restart dovecot
```

Check that the dovecot service is running

```
sudo systemctl status dovecot
```

Comment: This didn't work the issue for me. I will put in a comment what needed to be done.

Answer (score -1):

I got the email working by changing the ssl/tls configuration in dovecot. Make sure you have dovecot-2.3. All commands are done from the terminal. I first created a new Diffie Hellman parameters file.

```
cd /etc/dovecot`
openssl dhparam 4096 > dh.pem`
```

I removed the following lines in file “/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf”

```
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
```

I added and modified the following lines in file “/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf”

```
ssl_dh =</etc/dovecot/dh.pem
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:!kRSA:!SRP:!kDHd:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW:!DH@STRENGTH
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
```

Restart the dovecot service

```
sudo systemctl restart dovecot
```

Check that the dovecot service is running

```
sudo systemctl status dovecot
```

Comment: This makes no sense: You are creating DH param but you explicitly disable DH in your cipher list. And while you keep ECDH(E) the DH param are no use for this. Also, setting the min protocol to TLSv1.2 will keep older clients away.  In other words: you've got some error, fiddled a bit with the settings until it worked for your specific case without understanding what you actually did. This does not make an answer which is useful for others with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I took the cipher list recommendation and steps from the dovecot wiki. I will test by disabling the DH parameter and then modify the post if it is not required.

Comment: To S. Ullrich.  I tried removing the line "openssl dhparam 4096 > dh.pem" however I still get tls handshake errors in evolution mail without this line and cannot get any mail. I am confused by it because the dovecot wiki for upgrade to 2.3 https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Upgrading/2.3, states it is not needed. From the wiki, "Since v2.3.3+ DH parameter usage is optional and can be omitted. You are invited to amend ciphers to disallow non-ECC based DH algorithms, but if you don't and someone does try to use them, error will be emitted."

Comment: I also changed the ssl cipher list to what is listed in the dovecot-2.3 wiki.